# Trying to display in a simple php system mysql data with One to many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql

I have connected FirstPositionID/SecondPositionID with PositionID(PRIMARY KEY) from positions. Each positionID has one position name. Since i have 2 positions for players setted by position id, shouldn't php print position name of each id i have set?
 When i print PositionName it prints all positions i have inserted in my positions table.
here is my tables

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
`PlayerID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`PlayerName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`CountryID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`FirstPositionID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`SecondPositionID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Overall` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Defence` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Speed` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Rebound` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Stamina` int(11) NOT NULL,
`TeamID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Shooting` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16;

CREATE TABLE `positions` (
`PositionID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`PositionName` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16;





//-----------php-----------------------

    $sql= "SELECT * from players,positions";
    $reg = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($reg) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reg))
        {
            echo "</br>Player:".$row['PlayerName']." Overall:".$row['Overall']." Position: ".$row['PositionName'];
        }

    }
    else 
    {
        echo "SQL error at: </br> ".$register."SYNTAX:</br>".mysqli_error($con)."</br>";
    }
```

**RESULT:**

```
Player:Agrabanis Overall:64 Position: Point Guard

Player:Athineou Overall:64 Position: Point Guard

Player:Agrabanis Overall:64 Position: Shooting Guard

Player:Athineou Overall:64 Position: Shooting Guard

Player:Agrabanis Overall:64 Position: Small Forward

Player:Athineou Overall:64 Position: Small Forward

Player:Agrabanis Overall:64 Position: Power Forward

Player:Athineou Overall:64 Position: Power Forward

Player:Agrabanis Overall:64 Position: Center

Player:Athineou Overall:64 Position: Center
```

Since i have set to firstplayer position ids 5,4 and to the secondplayer position ids 2,1 shouldnt just print Center,Power Forward(4,5 position ids) for first player and for secondplayer Shooting Guard,Point Guard(2,1 position ids)

Comment: There's a kernel of a question here but no information about your schema or associated PHP code. Can you strip that example down to a minimal amount necessary to convey your problem and add the code?

Comment: I see what you *have* done - you've created a **cross-join** between `players` and `positions` - but I'm not clear on what you *wanted* to do. Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statements. Also, please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use `left join` or `inner join` instead of cross join and change your SQL string to something like

```
SELECT pl.PlayerName, pl.FirstPositionID, pl.Overall,
pl.SecondPositionID, po1.PositionName AS FirstPositionName,
po2.PositionName AS SecondPositionName FROM players pl
LEFT JOIN positions po1 ON(pl.FirstPositionID = po1.PositionID )
LEFT JOIN positions po2 ON (pl.SecondPositionID = po2.PositionID )
LIMIT 0,100
```

Also, change you while loop to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reg)){
  echo "</br>Player:".$row['PlayerName']." Overall:".$row['Overall']." Position1: ".$row['FirstPositionName']." Position2:".$row['SecondPositionName '];
}
```

I think this will helps you...

Comment: So you tell me to create 2 more columns with FirstPositionName and SecondPositionName for each PositionID from `players` table?
P.S: I edited the first post to be more readable!

Comment: No, You don't need to create new columns as I have used column alias instead(see **po1.PositionName AS FirstPositionName,
po2.PositionName AS SecondPositionName**). Also, I have joined table **positions** two times for **FirstPositionID** and **SecondPositionID** respectively